# MySql error when importing dump from linux into windows machine localhost

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, import

I get a couple of errors when trying to import a .sql dump file using the following command:

```
mysql -hIP -r -uroot -p db_test < C:\Users\Mark Hur\SQL Dumps\oct.sql;
```

The errors I get are as follows:

```
ERROR:
Unknown command '\U'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\O'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\P'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\D'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\S'.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\o'.
```

I guess these are due to the fact that I received a .sql dump from a database that resides on a linux machine. How do I import it then? **I want to to import the data only**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a long filename with spaces it needs to be quoted:

```
mysql -hIP -r -uroot -p db_test < "C:\Users\Mark Hur\SQL Dumps\oct.sql"
```

**Reference**:

[Long Filenames or Paths with Spaces Require Quotation Marks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/102739/long-filenames-or-paths-with-spaces-require-quotation-marks)